# Emacs can't send return at prompts

Tags: emacs

Sometimes in emacs I stop being able to send **return** in term, at prompts. A restart fixes it, but it is very frustrating. Virtualenv going, all the buffers I need open, and I'm cooking away. Then I try `rm file`, and I can't push **y** then **return**. I just get **^M**. I know **enter** send **c-M** in Emacs, but I can't sort out why this works for a while, then stops.

Obviously in this example I can just `rm -rf file`, but that isn't always the case.

Comment: Are you running a shell inside emacs, via `M-x shell`? Or are you closing / backgrounding emacs to run shell commands?

Comment: I am running via `M-x term`.